# Update ListView items appearance depending on screen position

Tags: android, listview

I have the following problem:

I have a ListView in my android app. Each item of this list view has 2 TextViews (say, left and right). I want to achieve the following effect: the left TextView is always visible, the right TextView is visible only if it's located in the upper half of the screen, and its visibility changes when the user scrolls the ListView.

```
+-------+   
|l1   r1|
|l2   r2| <= initial positions, r3 and r4 aren't displayed
|l3     |
|l4     |
+-------+

+-------+   
|l3   r3|
|l4   r4| <= the user has scrolled the list up, r3 and r4 are displayed
|l5     |
|l5     |
+-------+
```

How to achieve such effect?

My ListView uses an adapter, extended from BaseAdapter, the adapter looks like

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
private List<Item> items;

....

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_list_item_view, viewGroup, false);
    }

    Item item = items.get(i);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.l)).setText(item.key);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.r)).setText(item.value);
    return view;
}
```

}

I'd be happy to be able to change visibility of the right TextView inside getView(), but this method isn't called when the list is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand BaseAdapter, the getView() method is called only when Android is creating an item to show on screen. If the item is already on screen, the getView() won't be called.

Comment: Exactly, that's what prevents me from updating visibility inside this method.

Comment: Please have a look at listview onScrollListener. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741645/how-to-implement-onscrolllistener-to-a-listview.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution.

```
        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            for (int index = 0; index < i1; index++) {
                View child = listView.getChildAt(index);
                if (child != null) {
                    int[] out = new int[2];
                    child.getLocationOnScreen(out);
                    int alpha = (800 - out[1]);
                    if (alpha < 0) alpha = 0;
                    if (alpha > 255) alpha = 255;
                    ((TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.r)).setTextColor(Color.argb(alpha, 60, 60, 60));
                }
            }
        }
    });
```