# Hiding FAB when the user scroll through screen

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, scrollbar, floating-action-button

my problem is I want to hide the Love FAB when the user scroll down to reviews and shows again when the user goes up again
how can i achieve this behaviour ?

[image]

and this is what looks like now

[image]

my XML file is this:

[FAB.xml](https://gist.github.com/alihabbash/c7d6439eb21be93190b62a34839656ed)

I  cannot post it here because it's so long.

Comment: You could set the visibility property to `GONE` or `INVISIBLE`

Comment: Yeah that's what i want, but how can i set the visibility to be gone when the user scroll away from the product image to reviews?

Comment: If you are using a `ListView` you can implement the `OnScrollListener`  :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741645/how-to-implement-onscrolllistener-to-a-listview

Comment: I have a nestedScrollView does it has the same concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Barns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8039298/barns) I have come with the solution
by set the visibility property to `GONE` or `INVISIBLE`

and implementing the `nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener`

this code sample works fine for me:

```
        nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

            //the Y-axis scroll origin value
            if( scrollY > 275) {
                Log.i("Scroll", "onScrollChange: 275 Reached");
                loveFab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else
                loveFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    });
```